# sap.m.MultiInput.WaitForAsyncValidation in TypeScript App

Tags: typescript, sapui5

I am on my first typscript app using the easy-ui5 ts-app generator as template.
In there I am using a MultiInput and inside it's validator I have an oData read, to make sure any giving value is valid and corresponds to an existing item.

This is done like here:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.MultiInput/sample/sap.m.sample.MultiInputValidators/code/controller/MultiInputValidators.controller.js

The Problem: Typescript Syntax check throws following error:
`Property 'WaitForAsyncValidation' does not exist on type 'typeof MultiInput'`

I have imported the control like this:
`import MultiInput from "sap/m/MultiInput";`

The Code works no problem, but the Syntax check implies, that there is something I do wrong.
Does anyone know how to fix this / know what I am doing wrong?
"full" Controller

```
import MultiInput from "sap/m/MultiInput";
...
public onInit(): void {
...
const oPoduktMI: MultiInput = this.byId("idProduktMultiInput") as MultiInput;
oPoduktMI.addValidator(function (args: Validator) {
    //oDataCall
        args.asyncCallback( new Token({
            key: avalue,
            text: anothervalue,
        }));
    return MultiInput.WaitForAsyncValidation;
}
```

edit:
Git Hub Issue:
https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3626

Comment: `WaitForAsyncValidation` is not publicly visible in the API reference (yet?). Please [create an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/new) about the usage of undocumented field in the linked sample code.

Comment: In the meantime if you are 200% sure this property should exist you could do the following tempfix:

`interface AsyncMultiInput extends MultiInput { WaitForAsyncValidation: string }` and then do `this.byId("idProduktMultiInput") as AsyncMultiInput`